# System.NotSupportedException Could not find Microsoft Silverlight SDK 5.0

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012, as I create a Silverlight project from scratch, it doesn't allows me to see or edit the design section of the XAML , getting this error.

But I can build the project without errors or warnings, and nonetheless it displays in a browser without trouble.

How can I not have the SDK installed and still be able to run the project or for that matter, have created it in the first place?

I've been searching for a while and couldn't find a solution that makes sense, here are some of the links I've found:

- This guy states he used this console command

  > **secedit /configure /cfg %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose**

  that restores security settings to a known working
  state....http://sergiotardio.blogspot.mx/2012/06/could-not-find-microsoft-silverlight.html
- http://blog.arvixe.com/how-to-fix-could-not-find-microsoft-silverlight-sdk-v4-0/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34b26e8f-7529-422b-9fab-42d58fcff6c8/vs-2010-could-not-find-microsoft-silverlight-sdk-v30?forum=vswpfdesigner

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I had installed the Microsoft Silverlight Tools for Visual Studio, so I could create new projects, but the SDK as it is, I have not.
What really confused me is that the SDK System Requirements didn't explicitly say is supported for Windows 8.1 (The OS I'm working on), so I went searching somewhere else.
The solution was ignore this issue, download it, and install it.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28359
[image]